# MySQL table entries not showing up

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I began building a CMS for a blog today, and have had trouble getting the two entries I manually inserted via phpMyAdmin to show up on the page. It might be an issue with the database, might be an issue with the code, but for some reason the MySQL table iterates through only once with blank entries. Here is the PHP:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    if (!$link)
        die('<h3>Cound not connect to MySQL<h3><p><div>'.mysql_error()."</p></div>");
    mysql_select_db('blog_cms', $link);
    $posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries");
    if ($posts == null) die ("<h3>No blog posts found!</h3><div><p>Something went wrong.</p></div>");
    else
        while ($entry = mysql_fetch_row($posts)); {
            echo "<h3>".$entry[0]."</h3>";
            echo "<div>";
            echo "<p>".$entry[1]."</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
```

And for the output HTML I am simply getting

```
<h3></h3><div><p></p></div>
```

Screenshot of phpMyAdmin
[image: PMA screenshot]

Why is this only returning a single blank row?

Comment: " might be an issue with .." the onus is on you to do some debugging to determine that

Comment: Did you commit your inserts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra **;** after your while loop That's why the next block is not associated with this loop any more.

```
 while ($entry = mysql_fetch_row($posts));
                                         A
```

remove the extra `;` and it should work fine :) And please note that mysql_* functions are deprecated. Start using PDO or mysqli_*.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you; I should have seen that.

Comment: don't mix mysqli_* with mysql_* :) Start learning here http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php